# Merge two arrays and sort the final one

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

In an interview I was asked the following question. 
I am given two arrays, both of them are sorted.

BUT

Array 1 will have few -1's and Array 2 will have total numbers as the total number of -1's in Array 1.

So in the below example
array1 has three -1's hence array2 has 3 numbers.

let say

```
var arrayOne = [3,6,-1,11,15,-1,23,34,-1,42];
var arrayTwo = [1,9,28];
```

Both of the arrays will be sorted.

Now I have to write a program that will merge arrayTwo in arrayOne by replacing -1's, and arrayOne should be in sorted order.

So the output will be

```
arrayOne = [ 1,3, 6, 9, 11, 15, 23, 28 ,34, 42 ]
```

Sorting should be done without use of any sort API.

I have written a following code

```js
function puzzle01() {
  var arrayOne = [3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42];
  var arrayTwo = [1, 9, 28];
  var array1Counter = 0,
    isMerged = false;

  console.log(" array-1 ", arrayOne);
  console.log(" array-2 ", arrayTwo);

  for (var array2Counter = 0; array2Counter < arrayTwo.length; array2Counter++) {
    isMerged = false;
    while (isMerged === false && array1Counter < arrayOne.length) {

      if (arrayOne[array1Counter] === -1) {
        arrayOne[array1Counter] = arrayTwo[array2Counter];
        isMerged = true;
      }

      array1Counter++;
    }
  } //for

  console.log(" array-1 + array-2 ", arrayOne);
  bubbleSort(arrayOne);
  console.log(" Sorted array ", arrayOne);
} //puzzle01

puzzle01();

// implementation of bubble sort for sorting the 
// merged array
function bubbleSort(arrayOne) {
  var nextPointer = 0,
    temp = 0,
    hasSwapped = false;
    
  do {
    hasSwapped = false;
    for (var x = 0; x < arrayOne.length; x++) {
      nextPointer = x + 1;
      if (nextPointer < arrayOne.length && arrayOne[x] > arrayOne[nextPointer]) {
        temp = arrayOne[x];
        arrayOne[x] = arrayOne[nextPointer];
        arrayOne[nextPointer] = temp;
        hasSwapped = true;
      }
    } //for
  } while (hasSwapped === true);
} // bubbleSort
```

The output of the above code is

```
 array-1  [ 3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42 ]
 array-2  [ 1, 9, 28 ]
 array-1 + array-2  [ 3, 6, 1, 11, 15, 9, 23, 34, 28, 42 ]
 Sorted array  [ 1, 3, 6, 9, 11, 15, 23, 28, 34, 42 ]
```

From the above code you can see, I have first merged the two arrays and than sorted the final one.

Just wanted to know,
Is there a better solution.

Is there any flaw in my solution.

Please let me know, it will be helpfull.

After reading all your very helpful comments and answers, I found was able to figure out a more faster solution.

Let us take an example

```
var arrayOne = [3,6,-1,11,15,-1,32,34,-1,42,-1];
var arrayTwo = [1,10,17,56],
```

Step1: I will iterate through arrayTwo. Take the next element (i.e. '1') and compare with next element of arrayOne (i.e. '3') and compare.

step 2a : If element of array1 is greater than element of array2 than swap array elements. Now go to next element of array1.

OR

step 2b : If element of array1 is equal to -1 than swap array elements. Now go to next element of array2.

step 3: Go to step 1.

So

in the above example

first iteration,
    array1 = [1,6,-1,11,...]
    array2 = [3,10,17,56]

second iteration,
    array1 = [1,3,-1,11,..]
    array2 = [6,10,17,56]

third iteration,
    array1 = [1,3,6,11..]
    array2 = [-1,10,17,56]

fourth iteration
    array1 = [1,3,6,10,..]
    array2 = [-1,11,17,56]

and so on.

at the end I will get the output

```
array1 = [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 32, 34, 42, 56 ]
array2 = [-1,-1,-1]
```

Please find the code below,

```
function puzzle02(arrayOne,arrayTwo){   
    var array1Counter = 0,
        array2Counter = 0,       
        hasMinusOneOccurred = false;

    console.log(" array-1 ",arrayOne);
    console.log(" array-2 ",arrayTwo);  


    while(array2Counter < arrayTwo.length){ // iterate through array2

        do{
            if(arrayOne[array1Counter] === -1){ // if -1 occurred in array1
                hasMinusOneOccurred = true;

                // swaping numbers at current position of array1
                // with current position of array2 
                swap(arrayOne,arrayTwo,array1Counter,array2Counter);

                // recheck if the current value is greater than other values
                // of array1
                if(recheckAndSort(arrayOne,array1Counter) === true){
                    array1Counter = -1;// recheck array1 from start
                }else{
                    // recheck the current array1 counter, for doing so go 1 count back
                    // so that even if the counter is incremented it points to current
                    // number itself 
                    array1Counter--; 
                }

            }else if(arrayOne[array1Counter] > arrayTwo[array2Counter]){
                swap(arrayOne,arrayTwo,array1Counter,array2Counter);
            }else{
                array1Counter++;
                continue;   
            }

            array1Counter++;            
        }while(hasMinusOneOccurred === false); // end of do-while

        array2Counter++;
        hasMinusOneOccurred = false;

    }//end of while

    console.log(" Sorted array ",arrayOne);

    function swap(arr1,arr2,arr1Index,arr2Index){
        var temp = arr2[arr2Index];
        arr2[arr2Index] = arr1[arr1Index];
        arr1[arr1Index] = temp;
    }// end of swap 

    // this method is call if -1 occures in array1
    function recheckAndSort(arrayOne,array1Counter){
        var isGreaterVal = true,
            prevCounter = 0,
            nextCounter = 0,
            temp = 0,
            recheckFromStart = false;


        if(array1Counter === 0){ // if -1 occurred at first position of array1.

            // flag to check if -1 occurrec at first position
            // if yes, iterate array1 from start
            recheckFromStart = true; 

            // iterate forward to check wether any numbers are less than current position,
            // if yes than move forward
            for(var j = 0; isGreaterVal; j++){
                nextCounter = j + 1;

                if(arrayOne[nextCounter] === -1){
                    // swaping numbers of array1 between next to current                    
                    swap(arrayOne,arrayOne,nextCounter,j);
                    isGreaterVal = true; 

                }else if(arrayOne[nextCounter] < arrayOne[j]){
                    // swaping numbers of array1 between next to current
                    swap(arrayOne,arrayOne,nextCounter,j);
                    isGreaterVal = true;

                }else{
                    isGreaterVal = false;
                }

             }//end of for

         }else{// if -1 occurred in the middle position of array1 and is been swaped then
            // iterate backwards to check if any number less then current position exists,
            // if yes than shift backwards.
            for(var i = array1Counter; isGreaterVal; i--){
                prevCounter = i - 1;

                if(arrayOne[prevCounter] > arrayOne[i]){

                    // swaping numbers of array1 between previous to current                    
                    swap(arrayOne,arrayOne,prevCounter,i);
                    isGreaterVal = true; 
                }else{
                    isGreaterVal = false;
                }

            }// end of for  
        }

        return recheckFromStart;        
    }// end of recheckAndSort
} // end of puzzle02
```

After calling the above function

```
puzzle02([3,6,-1,11,15,-1,32,34,-1,42,-1],[1,10,17,56]);
```

The output of above code is,

```
 array-1  [ 3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 32, 34, -1, 42, -1 ]
 array-2  [ 1, 10, 17, 56 ]
 Sorted array  [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 32, 34, 42, 56 ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the number of `-1`s in the first array equal to the length of the second array?

Comment: *Without any sort API*, do you mean you just can't use `Array#sort`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is seeking improvements/ optimisations and belongs to CodeReviews

Comment: You should be able to do this by just iterating through the arrays using a counter - and swapping the values. No need for a sort algorithm, because they are already sorted. It's about merging.

Comment: In your initial statement the numbers in array two could just be substituted into the first array in place of the -1s in order. In your actual code you are using a different set of values which doesn't have that property. Can you explain why your inputs are different in your question and your code and which ones are correct?

Comment: @Chris: the case of all -1 at the right places would be trivial to solve, but you are right to raise this.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, but it is an interview question - it isn't necessarily meant to be hard. IT could easily be a question about how to iterate through two lists simultaneously (and in fact I'd say the situation where the -1s don't line up isn't actually that much harder anyway).

Comment: @chris: "where the -1s line up" what do you mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That was meant to read "don't line up" (And I've edited original comment). By which I mean it isn't just a case of subbing array two values into array one where the -1s are. The latter is just a case of looping through both arrays taking the smaller number each time and ignoring -1s. Its still trivial.

Comment: @Chris: no, I suspect that there is an in-place solution in O(N) operations, but still elusive on the moment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I guess you could try to do that but it feels a lot like premature optimisation to do so. I'm struggling to think of a real world situation where you would be programming in javascript and performance was so critical that you had to do it in place in O(N). If an interviewer demanded I do that I'd seriously question his reasoning. And I would personally consider an over-engineered harder to read solution to be worse than the obvious one which is O(N) but not in place.

Comment: @Chris: I have found an efficient in-place solution. It is actually faster than the obvious merge with an auxiliary array, as it moves the elements of arrayOne twice, but those of arrayTwo only once. I got the job, the were after an algorithmician. :-)

Comment: If you find a better solution, please post it as an answer and accept it, instead of editing it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following approach:

#### Logic

- Create a new array that will be returned.
- Check for first element in `arrayTwo` and keep it in a variable say `val`.
- Loop over `arrayOne` and check if current value is greater than `val`, push it in array and decrement value of `i` by 1 to check next value as well with current element.
- Now check for current element. If it is less than `0`, ignore it, else push value to array.
- Return this array.

```js
function mergeAndSort(a1, a2) {
  var matchCount = 0;
  var ret = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    var val = a2[matchCount];
    if (a1[i] > val) {
      ret.push(val)
      matchCount++
      i--;
      continue;
    }
    if (a1[i] > 0) {
      ret.push(a1[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(ret.join())
  return ret;
}


var arrayOne = [3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42]
var arrayTwo = [7, 19, 38];
var arrayThree = [1, 9, 28];
var arrayFour = [1,2,5]

mergeAndSort(arrayOne, arrayTwo)
mergeAndSort(arrayOne, arrayThree)
mergeAndSort(arrayOne, arrayFour)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Note:** Not putting check for number of elements in `arrayTwo` as its clearly mentioned in question that it will be same.

Comment: it is easy to use a new array, but should `arrayOne` contain the result?

Comment: *"Not putting check for number of elements in arrayTwo as its clearly mentioned in question that it will be same."* what does it mean?

Comment: @NinaScholz if you see I'm not checking length of arrayTwo. So if you have  3 `-1` in arrayone and 4 elements in arrayTwo, all four will be added. Also yes it's difficult to manipulate same array but you can just do `a1=ret` in my code and it would do the trick. Still you have way more knowledge than me so please lemme know if anything is missing or can be improved. :-)

Comment: but the length of `arrayTwo` is the count of `-1`. why not use the length of `arrayTwo`?

Comment: @NinaScholz i meant if number of -1 is 3 and length of array2 is 4 or more, then all will be added. We would have to count  -1 which would take more iteration. But as op has clearly said it will have same length, I'm not checking. Also didn't wanted anyone to downvote or spam with this case so added a caveat.

Comment: i actually fill the rest with `arrayTwo` parts.

Answer (score 2):

There is a clean O(N) in-place solution.

First "pack" `arrayOne` by moving all `-1` (`--` below) to the front. This takes a single backward pass.

Then perform a merge by iteratively moving the smallest element among `arrayTwo` and the tail of `arrayOne` and overwriting the next `--`. The gap will narrow down but there will always remain room for the elements of `arrayTwo`.

```
 3,  6, --, 11, 15, --, 23, 34, --, 42
 1,  9, 28
```

Packing:

```
 3,  6, --, 11, 15, --, 23, 34, --, 42

 3,  6, --, 11, 15, --, 23, --, 34, 42

 3,  6, --, 11, 15, --, --, 23, 34, 42

 3,  6, --, 11, --, --, 15, 23, 34, 42

 3,  6, --, --, --, 11, 15, 23, 34, 42

 3, --, --, --,  6, 11, 15, 23, 34, 42

 --, --, --, 3,  6, 11, 15, 23, 34, 42
```

Merging:

```
  --, --, --,  3,  6, 11, 15, 23, 34, 42
   1,  9, 28

   1, --, --,  3,  6, 11, 15, 23, 34, 42
  --,  9, 28

   1,  3, --, --,  6, 11, 15, 23, 34, 42
  --,  9, 28

   1,  3,  6, --, --, 11, 15, 23, 34, 42
  --,  9, 28

   1,  3,  6,  9, --, 11, 15, 23, 34, 42
  --, --, 28

   1,  3,  6,  9, 11, --, 15, 23, 34, 42
  --, --, 28

   1,  3,  6,  9, 11, 15, --, 23, 34, 42
  --, --, 28

   1,  3,  6,  9, 11, 15, 23, --, 34, 42
  --, --, 28

   1,  3,  6,  9, 11, 15, 23, 28, 34, 42
  --, --, --
```

Comment: at start, when you try to put all -1s to the begining, you have to shift entire array for each -1, sto thats not O(n) but O(n^2) in worst case

Comment: @MilanMarkovic: You work from the right and shift the elements directly to their final position. This is perfectly O(N).

Comment: 3, 6, --. you put -- in [0] and get --, 6, 3, not a sorted array

Comment: @MilanMarkovic: I am afraid that you missed the explanation. 3, 6, -- then 3, --, 6, then --, 3, 6.

Comment: another explanation: what you are actually doing there is re-sorting the array, so the minimum you can have is o(n logn)

Comment: @MilanMarkovic: this is a merge, well known to be O(N). Stop the harrassment.

Comment: whatever, not O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate `arrayOne` in a single loop and then `arrayTwo`.

The idea is to separate the target index from the actual index. The first loop ignores `-1` and and keep the target index.

If an actual value is greater then the first value of `arrayTwo`, both values swapped and in arrayTwo takes a sorting place by iterating and swapping with grater values.

Then the actual item is assigned to the target index.

Both indices gets incremented.

At the end all items of `arrayTwo` are added to `arrayOne`.

```js
function order(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
    var i = 0, j, l = 0;
    while (i < arrayOne.length) {
        if (arrayOne[i] === -1) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if (arrayTwo[0] < arrayOne[i]) {
            [arrayOne[i], arrayTwo[0]] = [arrayTwo[0], arrayOne[i]];
            j = 0;
            while (arrayTwo[j] > arrayTwo[j + 1]) {
                [arrayTwo[j], arrayTwo[j + 1]] = [arrayTwo[j + 1], arrayTwo[j]];
                j++;
            }
        }
        arrayOne[l++] = arrayOne[i++];
    }
    j = 0;
    while (l < arrayOne.length) {
        arrayOne[l++] = arrayTwo[j++];
    }
    return arrayOne;
}

console.log(order([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42], [7, 19, 38]));
console.log(order([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42], [1, 9, 28]));
console.log(order([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42], [1, 2, 5]));
console.log(order([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42], [43, 44, 45]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please check code snippet. `arrayTwo` is `[1,9,28]`. Just replacing will not do. You will have to sort it as well

Comment: Sorry if I'm bugging but this will fail for cases like `[1,2,5]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like `insertion sort`. As both the arrays are sorted (except -1s), the smallest number in `array2` will be placed somewhere between first element and the first -1, 2nd element of `array2` will be placed somewhere anywhere after the 1st -1 in `array1` and before or at the 2nd -1 in `array1` and so on.

So you have to insert a particular element of `array2` in only a segment of `array1` and not the whole array. Also each element of `array2` have to consider different segment or subarray of `array1`. So, effective time complexity of this logic will be `O(n+m)` where `n` is the length of `array1` and `m` is the length of `array2`.

Comment: This is a merge question, rather than sort - but I guess you're already recommending that?

Comment: @MaviDomates My logic is not exactly like an insertion sort. In actual insertion sort you have to start comparison from the end of the array but in my logic, comparison only starts from the index before corresponding -1 of `array1`. My solution is effectively the merge part of merge sort (but from opposite direction of `array1`).
If my logic recommends sorting, then it should consider all the elements for comparison, but it is not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be something like

compare each item of arrayTwo with each item of arrayOne
If it comes to bigger that that of arrayOne, insert the item and while iterating arrayOne delete all the -1 .

Answer (score 0):

That's actually an interesting question. There are many sorting algorithms, and the most efficient ones always starts from one "unchangeable" array, so without changing the values inside that. Yet here your goal is to change the value when it encounters -1, so that the value is taken from the second array.

So, you need a sorting algorithm that doesn't divide the array in pieces because if the last element of your second array is 1 (the lowest), it has to be moved to the start. If you're using a sorting algorithm that breaks the array in pieces (the divide-and-conquer tactic like quick sort) or that uses recursion, it can be problematic because it cannot be moved to the start of your main array. Unless you are aware of the main array.

What you need is an algorithm that performs a step-by-step algorithm.

The algorithm that I've used is a bubble sort, which checks each element step by step. It's then easier to replace the value if it's -1 and move its position correctly to the array. However, it is not so efficient. Maybe I will edit my post to see if I can improve that.

```js
function mergeAndSort(arr1, arrMergeIn) {
  // merge + sort using arr1 as large one
  var mergeIndex = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
    if (arr1[i] === -1) arr1[i] = arrMergeIn[mergeIndex++];
    var j = i;
    while (j > 0 && arr1[j - 1] > arr1[j]) {
      var tmp = arr1[j - 1];
      arr1[j - 1] = arr1[j];
      arr1[j] = tmp;
      j--
    }
  }
  return arr1;
}

// one liner console output
function showArray(arr) {
console.log(arr.join(','));
}


showArray(mergeAndSort([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42], [7, 19, 38]));

showArray(mergeAndSort([3, 36, -1, 1, 10, -1, 9, 34, -1, 42], [17, 9, 38]));

showArray(mergeAndSort([3, 36, -1, 1, 10, -1, 9, 34, -1, 42], [17, 9, 1]));

showArray(mergeAndSort([-1, 36, -1, 1, 10, -1, 9, 34, -1, 42], [17, 9, 100, 1]));

showArray(mergeAndSort([-1, -1, 1, 100, -1, 9, 34, -1], [17, 9, 9, 1]));
```

Or, you can use another strategy: replace the "-1" elements with the elements from that another array and perform an efficient algorithm on that. Although in worst-case scenario's, the "-1"s are at the end of the array, which means that there is an ~N operation + additional average complexity of a sorting algorithm (the efficient ones are of ~N*log(N))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and compact implementation of the merge sort algorithm. There will only be the same amount of operations as there are elements.

I achieve this by creating an array with the same number of elements as both arrays combined, then iterating that array.

Upon each iteration:

- If both arrays have elements (and the smallest element is not -1) it will move the smallest element into the result.
- If only one of the arrays still has elements (and the next element is not -1), it will move the first element from that array into the result.

Finally assign the result to the first array as per your spec

```js
const mergeSort = (a, b) => Object.assign(a, 
  new Int32Array(a.length + b.length).reduce(m => {
    const el = [
      [a, b][+!(a[0] <= b[0])], 
      [a, b][+!a.length]][+!(a.length && b.length)
    ].shift()
    if(el !== -1) m.push(el)
    return m
  }, [])
)

const arr1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
const arr2 = [0,2,4]

mergeSort(arr1, arr2)

console.log(arr1) // [0,1,2,3,4,5,7,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-phrase three most important aspects of the task:

- Both arrays are sorted and include positive integers (except -1 place-holders in Array1)
- The -1 is meaningless placeholder (its position in Array1 is random)
- Array1 length equals output array length

Pseudo logic:

- parse both array1 and array2 from the first position to end of array
- ignore -1 values in array1
- if array1[current position] <= array2[current position] then write array1[current position] into merged array and move to next position in array1; otherwise apply same for array2

Code example:

```
            public static void AMerge()
        {
            int[] array1 = new int[] { 3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42 };
            int[] array2 = new int[] { 1, 9, 28 };
            int[] arrayMerged = new int[array1.Length];

            int array1Index = 0;
            int array2Index = 0;

            for (int arrayMergedIndex = 0; arrayMergedIndex < array1.Length; arrayMergedIndex++)
            {
                while (array1[array1Index] == -1) array1Index++; //ignore -1 placeholders
                if ((array1Index < array1.Length && array2Index >= array2.Length) 
                    || array1[array1Index] <= array2[array2Index])  //choose which array will provide current merged value
                {
                    arrayMerged[arrayMergedIndex] = array1[array1Index];
                    array1Index++;
                }
                else
                {
                    arrayMerged[arrayMergedIndex] = array2[array2Index];
                    array2Index++;
                }
            }

            char[] charsToTrim = { ',', ' '};
            string arrayMergedString = "{";
            foreach (int f in arrayMerged) arrayMergedString += f.ToString() + " ";
            arrayMergedString = arrayMergedString.TrimEnd(charsToTrim) + "}";
            Console.WriteLine(arrayMergedString);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Note:

- Optimizing for speed => creating new arrayMerged; optimization for space would require moving array1 elements in the else branch

Answer (score -1):

You should use merge function from [Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), and modify it so that it doesn't create a new array, but instead uses array1, and perform translation, after insertion of an element from array2, that will shift elements to the right until the next -1, and thus overwrite the -1.

Comment: This can be time consuming because you can shift the whole array many times, leading to O(N²) cost.

Comment: Well, you have to decide whether you are going for the space or performance complexity... if you just create a new array then you don't need shifting, but space becomes O(N)

Comment: Mh, the question is lacking any info about time and space requirements... IMO, O(N²) is a little catastrophy when O(N) is enough...

Comment: But maybe is it possible to shift the elements in arrayOne only once ?

Comment: Right now I'm thinking that maybe shifting isn't necessary... theoretically, you don't use any data when overwriting -1, so it could be done from just the modified merge

Comment: It can be that no element is at the right place and variable amounts of shifting required. This is the very reason why in-place merging is very difficult.

Comment: Yes... just realized that -1's could also be for example at the start of the array, which adds a new dimension to the problem... so creating a new array is definitely a way to go.

Comment: But then again, having -1's is implicitly asking for solution with O(1) space complexity...

Answer (score -1):

```js
function merger(a1, a2) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;

  while (i < a1.length && j < a2.length) {
    if (a1[i] > a2[j]) {
      // Swap values
      var temp = a2[j];
      a2[j] = a1[i];
      a1[i] = temp;
      i++;
    } else if (a1[i] !== -1 && a1[i] <= a2[j]) {
      i++;
    } else {
      var temp = a2[j];
      a2[j] = a1[i];
      a1[i] = temp;
      i++;
      j++;
    }
  }

  return a1;
}

var arrayOne = [3, 5, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42];
var arrayTwo = [6, 19, 38];

console.log(merger(arrayOne, arrayTwo))
```

With certain pre-conditions (no other numbers with <0, a1 should be smaller than a2 etc - which could all be handled) this should solve the problem in JS.

Comment: Note this will fail if arrayTwo is `[1,2,5]`

Answer (score -1):

Since they are both sorted, the order of `arrayTwo`'s items should match the order of `-1`s in `arrayOne`. Then the job becomes simple and can be implemented as follows;

```js
function replaceMissing(a,b){
  var i = 0;
  return a.map(n => n < 0 ? b[i++] : n);
}
var arrayOne = [3,6,-1,11,15,-1,23,34,-1,42],
    arrayTwo = [7,19,38];
      result = replaceMissing(arrayOne,arrayTwo);
console.log(result);
```

Edit: I believe the upper solution does make more sense in the general logic of the question. If the position of -1s does not mean anything then what use do they have? Let's just delete the -1's and do a simple insertion of `arrayTwo` items at proper indices in `arrayOne`. This can very simply be done as follows.

```js
function replaceMissing(a,b){
  var j = b.length-1;
  return b.concat(a.reduceRight((r,m,i) => (m < 0 ? r.splice(i,1)
                                                  : m < b[j] && r.splice(i+1,0,b.splice(j--,1)[0]),
                                            r), a.slice()));
}
var arrayOne = [3,6,-1,11,15,-1,23,34,-1,42],
    arrayTwo = [1,25,38];
      result = replaceMissing(arrayOne,arrayTwo);
console.log(result);
```