# Merge two sorted arrays into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Hi I was asked a following question.

Given two arrays i.e. array1 and array2. Both of them contain numbers in sorted order.

Array1 also contains -1 such as; as many numbers in array2 that many -1's in array1.

Example as follows,

```
array1 = [-1,-1,-1,-1,56,78,90,1200];
array2 = [1,4,5,1000]
```

I need to write a program which merge the above arrays in one, which will contain numbers from both the arrays in sorted order, except -1.

This is my code as follows,

```
 puzzle04([3,6,-1,11,15,-1,23,34,-1,42],[1,12,28]);
 puzzle04([3,6,-1,11,15,-1,23,34,-1,42],[7,19,38]);
 puzzle04([3,6,11,15,32,34,42,-1,-1,-1,-1],[1,10,17,56]);
 puzzle04([-1,-1,-1,-1,3,6,11,15,32,34,42],[1,10,17,56]);
 puzzle04([-1,-1,-1,-1,3,6,11,15,32,34,42],[56,78,90,100]);
 puzzle04([12,34,65,-1,71,85,90,-1,101,120,-1,200],[24,37,94]);
 puzzle04([3,6,-1,11,15,-1,32,34,-1,42,-1],[1,10,17,56]);
 puzzle04([-1,-1,-1,56,78,90,112],[1,4,5]);
 puzzle04([-1,-1,-1,-1,56,78,90,112],[1,4,5,1000]);
 puzzle04([-1,-1,-1,-1,56,78,90,1200],[1,4,5,1000]); 

 function puzzle04(array1,array2){

    var outputArray = [],
        array1Counter = 0, // counter for array1
        array2Counter = 0, // counter for array2
        isArray2NumPlaced = false, // has number from array2 found its position in output array ?       
        areAllArray2NumsFilled = false; // is number pushed in output array

    // iterating through array2 loop    
    for(array2Counter = 0; array2Counter < array2.length; array2Counter++){

        // iterating through array1 loop
        for(; (isArray2NumPlaced === false); array1Counter++){

            // -1 encountered in array1
            if(array1[array1Counter] === -1){ 
                continue;

            // if array1 number is less than array2 number
            // then push array1 number in ouput array   
            }else if(array1[array1Counter] < array2[array2Counter]){

                outputArray.push(array1[array1Counter]);                

            }else{ // array2 number is less then array1 number

                // add array2 number in output array until
                // all array2 numbers are not added in output array.
                if(areAllArray2NumsFilled === false){
                    outputArray.push(array2[array2Counter]);    
                }               


                // is array2 number pushed in output array ?
                isArray2NumPlaced = true;

            }// end of if-else

            // if all the array2 numbers are added in output array
            // but still array1 numbers are left to be added
            if(isArray2NumPlaced === true 
            && array2Counter === (array2.length - 1) 
            && array1Counter <= (array1.length - 1)){

                outputArray.push(array1[array1Counter]);    

                // set the below flag to false so that,
                // array1 loop can iterate
                isArray2NumPlaced = false;

                // all the numbers of array2 are entered in output array
                areAllArray2NumsFilled = true;

            }// end of if

        }// array1 for-loops ends



        array1Counter--;
        isArray2NumPlaced = false;

    }// array2 for-loops ends


    console.log("final ",outputArray);  
}
```

The output of the above code is as follows,

```
final  [ 1, 3, 6, 11, 12, 15, 23, 28, 34, 42 ]
final  [ 3, 6, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 34, 38, 42 ]
final  [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 32, 34, 42, 56 ]
final  [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 32, 34, 42, 56 ]
final  [ 3, 6, 11, 15, 32, 34, 42, 56, 78, 90, 100 ]
final  [ 12, 24, 34, 37, 65, 71, 85, 90, 94, 101, 120, 200 ]
final  [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 11, 15, 17, 32, 34, 42, 56 ]
final  [ 1, 4, 5, 56, 78, 90, 112 ]
final  [ 1, 4, 5, 56, 78, 90, 112, 1000 ]
final  [ 1, 4, 5, 56, 78, 90, 1000, 1200 ]
```

When I showed my code to reviewer, he said I used too much boolean variables and the code can be lot more simpler.

I tried my best to improvise, but didn't got any clue.

Can you please suggest me any better way to solve above problem

Note: can't use any ready-made sorting methods or pre written api to solve above excercise.

Comment: Might be a better question for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Create a function that merges the arrays (regardless of value) and then sort them.  Most sort algorithms can be implemented in less code than what's presented and aren't that complex.

Comment: Do what @Skerkles is telling you and you'll probably get a `O(nm * log(nm))` time complexity, which isn't terrible.

Comment: Might want to do some research into the [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) functions in JavaScript...

Comment: What's you're describing is called a `merge sort` and can be implemented with a recursive "stitch" function

Comment: `puzzle04([3,6,-1,11,15,-1,23,34,-1,42],[1,12,28]);` <-- the numbers of the first array are not in sorted order?

Comment: They _are_ if you exclude -1

Comment: how differs this question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531614/merge-two-arrays-and-sort-the-final-one/42531787#42531787

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two arrays and sort the final one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531614/merge-two-arrays-and-sort-the-final-one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is step through both arrays, take the smaller of the two values, and add it to the output list. Once you have added all of one array, the remainder of the other array is all larger, and can be added in one go.

```
function merge(x, y) {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var result = [];

    while (i < x.length && j < y.length) {
        // Skip negative numbers
        if (x[i] === -1) {
            x += 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (y[j] === -1) {
            y += 1;
            continue;
        }

        // Take the smaller of the two values, and add it to the output.
        // Note: the index (i or j) is only incremented when we use the corresponding value
        if (x[i] <= y[j]) {
            result.push(x[i]);
            i += 1;
        } else {
            result.push(y[j]);
            j += 1;
        }
    }

    // At this point, we have reached the end of one of the two arrays. The remainder of
    // the other array is all larger than what is currently in the output array

    while (i < x.length) {
        result.push(x[i]);
        i += 1;
    }

    while (j < y.length) {
        result.push(y[j]);
        j += 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What if you had unknown number of arrays?

Comment: The same principle can apply here, but you'd need to use an array of indices, instead of the two variables `i` and `j`. Also, getting the smallest number in each iteration could become rather convoluted. I'd store the current number of each array in a min-heap, so taking the smallest number in each iteration becomes an `O(1)` operation, and adding the next number from that array in each iteration becomes an `O(log N)` operation

Answer (score 1):

```
function merge(array1, array2)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    array3; //answer
    while ( i<array1.size() and j<array2.size() ){

        if (array1[i] == -1 ) //ignore -1
        {   ++i; continue; }
        if (array2[j] == -1 ) //ignore -1
        {   ++j; continue; }

        if ( array1[i] < array2[j] ) { //choose the minor
            array3.push( array1[i] );
            ++i;
        }
        else {
            array3.push( array2[j] );
            ++j;    
        }
    }

    //if some array has elements still
    while (i < array1.size() )
        array3.push(array1[i]);
    while (j < array2.size() )
        array3.push(array1[j]);

    return array3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For stitching 2 sorted arrays together, you can do it as shown below. To add the functionality of omitting specific values, you can use `.filter()` to eliminate those elements prior to merging the arrays.

```js
function stitch(left, right) {
    left = left.filter(function (elem) { return elem !== -1; });
    right = right.filter(function (elem) { return elem !== -1; });
    var results = [];
    while (left.length && right.length) {
        if (left.length && right.length && (left[0] <= right[0])) {
            results.push(left.shift());
        } else {
            results.push(right.shift());
        }
    }

    return results.concat(left, right);
}

console.log(stitch([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42], [1, 12, 28]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function merge(array1, array2){
        var array = [];
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;
        while(i < array1.length || j < array2.length){
            if(array1[i] === -1){
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if(array1[i] && (!array2[j] || array1[i] <= array2[j])){
                array.push(array1[i]);
                i++;
            } else if(array2[j] && (!array1[i] || array2[j] <= array1[i])){
                array.push(array2[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.shift()` instead of keeping track of indexes, as I have done in my solution. Also, this does not check to see if `array2[i] === -1`. As a result, if there is a -1 in array2, it will end up in the array that gets returned, which I believe is undesired.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function puzzle04(arr1, arr2) 
{    
    var result = [];
    var final = [];
    var arr_concat = arr1.concat(arr2).filter(function (value) {
       return value != -1;
    });

    arr_concat.forEach(function(x) { 
        if(!result[x]) { 
            result[x] = []; 
            result[x].push('super sort'); 
        }
        else { 
            result[x].push('super sort'); 
        } 
    });

    result.forEach(function(k, v) { 
        k.forEach(function(x) {
            final.push(v); 
        }); 
    });

    console.log(final);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is [`mergeSort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort):

```
function puzzle04(array1, array2) {
  return mergeSortWithoutMinusOnes(array1.concat(array2))
}

function mergeSortWithoutMinusOnes(items){

  if (items.length < 2) {
    return items;
  }

  var middle = Math.floor(items.length / 2),
      left    = items.slice(0, middle),
      right   = items.slice(middle);

  return mergeWithoutMinusOnes(mergeSortWithoutMinusOnes(left), mergeSortWithoutMinusOnes(right));
}

function mergeWithoutMinusOnes(left, right){
  var result  = [],
      il      = 0,
      ir      = 0;

  while (il < left.length && ir < right.length){
    if (left[il] < right[ir]){
      if (left[il] === -1) {
        il++;
      } else {
        result.push(left[il++]);
      }
    } else {
      if (right[ir] === -1) {
        ir++
      } else {
        result.push(right[ir++]);
      } 
    }
  }

  return result.concat(left.slice(il)).concat(right.slice(ir));
}
```

From: https://github.com/nzakas/computer-science-in-javascript/blob/master/algorithms/sorting/merge-sort-recursive/merge-sort-recursive.js , with the modification to ignore minus ones.

Answer (score 1):

By taking your special `-1`s excluded condition into account; you may choose to merge multiple sorted arrays into one as follows;

```js
function merger(a,b,_,__,r = []){
  return !a.length ? !b.length ? r
                               : r.concat(b.filter(n => n > -1))
                   : !b.length ? r.concat(a.filter(n => n > -1))
                               : a[0] > -1 ? b[0] > -1 ? a[0] > b[0] ? (r.push(b[0]), merger(a,b.slice(1),_,__,r))
                                                                     : (r.push(a[0]), merger(a.slice(1),b,_,__,r))
                                                       : merger(a,b.slice(1),_,__,r)
                                           : merger(a.slice(1),b,_,__,r);
}

var arrs =  [[3,6,-1,11,15,-1,23,34,-1,42],[1,12,28],[3,6,-1,11,15,-1,23,34,-1,42],[7,19,38],[3,6,11,15,32,34,42,-1,-1,-1,-1],[1,10,17,56],[-1,-1,-1,-1,3,6,11,15,32,34,42],[1,10,17,56],[-1,-1,-1,-1,3,6,11,15,32,34,42],[56,78,90,100],[12,34,65,-1,71,85,90,-1,101,120,-1,200],[24,37,94],[3,6,-1,11,15,-1,32,34,-1,42,-1],[1,10,17,56],[-1,-1,-1,56,78,90,112],[1,4,5],[-1,-1,-1,-1,56,78,90,112],[1,4,5,1000],[-1,-1,-1,-1,56,78,90,1200],[1,4,5,1000]],
     res = arrs.reduce(merger);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: *"Note: can't use any ready-made sorting methods or pre written api to solve above excercise."*

Comment: @Nina Scholz I have just written it myself a few minutes ago. Sorry if it was implemented before.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over `arrayOne` in a single loop and then `arrayTwo`.

The idea is to separate the target index from the actual index. The first loop ignores `-1` and keeps the target index.

If an actual value is greater than the first value of `arrayTwo`, both values are swapped, and it takes a sorting place in `arrayTwo` by iterating over and swapping with grater values.

Then, the actual item is assigned to the target index.

Both indices gets incremented.

At the end, all `arrayTwo` items are added to `arrayOne`.

```js
function puzzle04(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
    var i = 0, j, l = 0;
    while (i < arrayOne.length) {
        if (arrayOne[i] === -1) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if (arrayTwo[0] < arrayOne[i]) {
            [arrayOne[i], arrayTwo[0]] = [arrayTwo[0], arrayOne[i]];
            j = 0;
            while (arrayTwo[j] > arrayTwo[j + 1]) {
                [arrayTwo[j], arrayTwo[j + 1]] = [arrayTwo[j + 1], arrayTwo[j]];
                j++;
            }
        }
        arrayOne[l++] = arrayOne[i++];
    }
    j = 0;
    while (l < arrayOne.length) {
        arrayOne[l++] = arrayTwo[j++];
    }
    return arrayOne;
}

console.log(puzzle04([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42], [1, 12, 28]));
console.log(puzzle04([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 23, 34, -1, 42], [7, 19, 38]));
console.log(puzzle04([3, 6, 11, 15, 32, 34, 42, -1, -1, -1, -1], [1, 10, 17, 56]));
console.log(puzzle04([-1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 6, 11, 15, 32, 34, 42], [1, 10, 17, 56]));
console.log(puzzle04([-1, -1, -1, -1, 3, 6, 11, 15, 32, 34, 42], [56, 78, 90, 100]));
console.log(puzzle04([12, 34, 65, -1, 71, 85, 90, -1, 101, 120, -1, 200], [24, 37, 94]));
console.log(puzzle04([3, 6, -1, 11, 15, -1, 32, 34, -1, 42, -1], [1, 10, 17, 56]));
console.log(puzzle04([-1, -1, -1, 56, 78, 90, 112], [1, 4, 5]));
console.log(puzzle04([-1, -1, -1, -1, 56, 78, 90, 112], [1, 4, 5, 1000]));
console.log(puzzle04([-1, -1, -1, -1, 56, 78, 90, 1200], [1, 4, 5, 1000]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem while developing a cryptocurrency price chart in my dapp.
I added my code here. You can reference my code to make one sorted array from two sorted arrays.

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 5, 6];
const array2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10];
const array = [];
let index = 0;
for (const one of array1) {
  do {
    if (array2[index] > one) break;
    else if (array2[index] < one) array.push(array2[index]);
  } while (index++ < array2.length);
  array.push(one);
}

array.push(...array2.splice(index));
console.log(array);
```