# How merge two arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

There are two arrays:

```
a1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];
a2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
```

How I get this:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

I wanna to use RxJs or else.

If the value isn‘t a number, like an Object.

```
 a1 = [A, C, E, G, I]; 
 a1 = [{'name': 'Lucy'}, {'name': 'Lily'}, {'name': 'Jerry'}, {'name': 'Tom'}, {'name': 'Smith'}]

 a2 = [B, D, F, H, J]; 
 a2 = [{'name': 'Jack'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Anan'}, {'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Dav'}]

 a = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J];
```

Comment: `a1.concat(a2)`

Comment: `a1.concat(a2).sort()` actually

Comment: a1.concat(a2).sort();

Comment: WHile I was typing... ;)

Comment: Do you want to sort by numeric value or lexicographically as strings?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922223/how-to-merge-two-sorted-array-in-one-sorted-array-in-javascript-without-using-so/31922374). [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817212/merge-two-sorted-arrays-into-one). [Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531614/merge-two-arrays-and-sort-the-final-one/42531787#42531787) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591403/what-is-faster-merge-2-sorted-arrays-into-a-sorted-array-w-o-duplicate-values).

Comment: Why you vote -1?

Comment: What do you mean by objects A B C D E? Post a valid example

Comment: I downvoted because your original question could be solved by a quick search, and your edit fundamentally changed the question, rendering answers obsolete. It's very unclear what you mean now, as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
[...a1,...a2].sort((a,b) => a-b)
```

That's ES6 syntax.

Comment: How should that work with objects ?!?

Answer (score 0):

With [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
a1 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8];
a2 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

a = a1.concat(a2).sort();

console.log(a)
```

Comment: How should that work with objects?!

Comment: He edited its question. Never talked about objects before

Comment: I just used number for a example....

Answer (score 0):

```
  const result = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length && i < arr2.length; i++)
    result.push(arr1[i], arr2[i]);

  result push(...arr1.slice(i), ...arr2.slice(i));
```

That merges two arrays (`arr1`, `arr2`) by taking one each.